# plotting a line chart by python using Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, linechart

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  from bokeh.palettes import Spectral11
  from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
  output_file('temp.html')
  toy_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(5,3), columns = ('a', 'b' ,'c'), index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='01-01-2015',periods=5, freq='d'))   
    numlines=len(toy_df.columns)
    mypalette=Spectral11[0:numlines]

    p = figure(width=500, height=300, x_axis_type="datetime") 
    p.multi_line(xs=[toy_df.index.values]*numlines,
            ys=[toy_df[name].values for name in toy_df],
            line_color=mypalette,
            line_width=5)
    show(p)
```

I have this code using Bokeh to have line chart, it works fine for one time but now i am getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named palettes
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You either have a *ancient* installation of Bokeh, or a broken one. `bokeh.palettes` was added in version 0.4, nearly three years ago.

Comment: I just installed everything and it works one time...if it is broken How shall I fix this?

Comment: File system and OS problems are basically impossible to debug without actually digging around the system. The best thing I can suggest is to re-install.